# Constructive proof that a linear relation between columns implies a linear relation between rows

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $M = \left(M_{ij}\right)$ be a square matrix and let $v = (v_{i}) \neq 0$ be such that $Mv = 0$. This can be rephrased into requiring that $\sum_{i} v_{i} M_{i} = 0$, where $\{M_{i}\}$ are the column vectors in $M$, i.e. $(v_{j})$ gives a linear relation on the columns of $M$. I can think of multiple proofs that the existence of $v$ implies the existence of a $w=(w_{j})$ such that $M^{t}w = 0$, but none of them are constructive.

How can we write done the coordinates of such a $w$ in terms of the coordinates of $v$ and $M$? In other words, how can we translate a linear relation of columns into a linear relation of rows?

To be more explicit, I would like a non-trivial expression $w_j = f(v,M)$ such that when I compute $\sum_j w_j M_j$ (where $M_j$ are the row vectors in $M$) I obtain $0$ by using the fact that $\sum_{i} v_{i} M_{i} = 0$. Does such an expression exist?

Comment: $M$ is a square matrix, right?

Comment: The proof that a matrix can be put in RREF is constructive, is it not?

Comment: $w$ will depend on $M$ as well as $v$, and $w$ can be found from $M$ alone, so I suspect the underlying question is whether $v$ helps in finding $w$

Comment: @Henry That $w$ depends on $M$ is a good point, I will adjust my question accordingly.

Comment: If $M$ need not be square then $M=[1,1]$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Whoops, that was a pretty big mistake, $M$ should be square. I have edited accordingly.

Comment: This can also be stated generally in terms of eigenvectors. Suppose a given matrix $M$ has a right eigenvector with a particular eigenvalue. Then there also exists a left eigenvector with this same eigenvalue. How do we construct it? (Obviously we can do so by brute force but that’s exactly what you want to avoid.) In even wider scope: Given the basis of right eigenvectors for $M$, how do we find the basis of left eigenvectors? (This last description smells like the singular value decomposition, particularly in that $M^t M$ and $MM^t$ have the same spectrum but different diagonalizations.)

Comment: I think the hard part here is that if you are treating the column vectors as your “preferred” space (Eg $M$ as a linear map from column vectors to column vectors), then a linear dependence in the rows is a vector $w$ “avoiding” the image of $M$, in the sense that $w^T M_i = 0$ for all columns $M_i$, or even $w^T M v =0$ for all $v$. To find such a $w$, knowledge of a $v$ in the kernel of $M$ is relatively useless, since we get the condition $w^T M v = w^T 0 = 0$ on $w$, which is to say no condition at all.

Comment: @Joppy Suppose we choose a basis of the space orthogonal to $v$. Would it be easier to write something down in terms of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you did not rule out the solution $f(v,M)=0$, but I'll assume this is not what you had in mind. So I'll assume that $w:=f(v,M)$ should satisfy the conditions:

1. $M^tf(v,M)=0$
2. $f(v,M)\neq 0$ for all $v,M$

The answer of course depends on what exactly you mean by an "expression", but what can be said is that if $M$ has an odd number of rows, then **the function $f$ cannot be continuous**.

Indeed, assume $M$ to have size (2k+1)x(2k+1), and denote the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^{2k+1}$ by $e_i$. Assume that there is a continuous function $f$ satisfying conditions (1) and (2).

Let $q\in S^{2k}\subset\mathbb{R}^{2k+1}$ denote a vector on the unit sphere of dimension $2k$, and define the family of matrices $M(q)=qe_1^t$. This is a continuous function $S^{2k}\to End(\mathbb{R}^{2k+1})$. Now consider $w(q)=f(e_2, M(q))$ (this makes sense because $M(q)e_2=0$ for all $q$). The map $q\mapsto w(q)$ satisfies:

- it is a continuous function of $q$ (since it is a composition of continuous functions)
- $q^tw(q)=0$ for all $q$ (Property 1+defn of $M(q)$)
- $w(q)\neq 0$ for all $q$ (Property 2)

By the Hairy Ball Theorem, such a map cannot exist. So either you will have to allow $f$ to be discontinuous, or accept that sometimes you will get the trivial answer $f(v,M)=0$.

Comment: A previous comment mentioned that putting a matrix in RREF gives a constructive proof that the vector $w$ exists. Your argument implies that, whatever this construction may be, it won't be continuous w.r.t. the entries of $M$. Can this also be understood directly (for example, can it be explained in terms of an arbitrary choice that must be made when putting a matrix in RREF)?

Comment: Well it should not be surprising that the RREF is not a continuous function of the entries. Indeed, $RREF([\epsilon,1])=[1,1/\epsilon]$ and $RREF([0,1])=[0,1]$.